# How do I use RegReplaceKey()?

Tags: delphi, winapi, registry

I'm trying to replace registry hive file by using `RegReplaceKey()` (new file is created with `RegSaveKey()` API), but it returns with **"file already exists"** error. If I try to delete original hive file first, it fails with an error **"file is in use"**.

I've assigned proper privileges (`SeBackupPrivilege` and `SeRestorePrivilege`), user is an administrator, but no luck.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong? Here's the code:

```
...

// Setting privileges here, everything goes okay

nret := RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'system', hk);

if nret = 0 then
begin
  RegFlushKey(hk);
  if FileExists('C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\testhive') then
    DeleteFile('C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\testhive');
  nret := RegSaveKey(hk, 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\testhive', nil);
  if nret <> 0 then
    MessageBox(0, pchar(SysErrorMessage(nret)), '', 0);

  // no errors so far, new file is created

  SeqNr := StartRestore('Before Registry Optimization');
  if FileExists('C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\system') then
  begin
    FileSetAttr('C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\system', 0);
    if not DeleteFile('C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\system') then
      MessageBox(0, pchar(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)), '', 0);
      // error: file is in use
  end;

  nret := RegReplaceKey(hk, nil, 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\testhive', 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\system');
  if nret <> 0 then
    MessageBox(0, pchar(SysErrorMessage(nret)), '', 0);
    // error: file already exists
  if SeqNr <> 0 then
    EndRestore(SeqNr);

  RegCloseKey(hk);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone has similar problem, I'll answer my own question.

The mistake was in last `RegReplaceKey()` parameter: it shouldn't point to actual and current hive registry file, but to **another temp file**:

```
  nret := RegReplaceKey(hk, nil, 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\testhive',
            'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\testhive1');
```

Consequently, prior to this line, we don't need to delete hive file itself, but the second temp file (to ensure it doesn't exist):

```
  if FileExists('C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\testhive1') then
  begin
    if not DeleteFile('C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\testhive1') then
      MessageBox(0, pchar(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)), '', 0);
  end;
```

If done this way, everything works ok, and Windows replaces key determined by `hk`, which was received from `RegOpenKey()`.

Answer (score 0):

RegReplaceKey sets up windows to use the file backing the registry on restarting windows.
You call it and provide a file.
On restart it will use it.
So I suspect it's not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Replacing after restart would be great, but it doesn't work. As I said above, call fails with "file already exists" error, and after restart it does nothing.